# Creating Sub Reports Total And Grand Total In Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report getting data from SQL Server. I want to generate GroupReport Total and also Generate Grand Total Report

I have been able to generate the report from SQL, the following are the fields i have: Item_Name, qty, Price, Amount

I have created a Formular to sum all the amount which the total will give me the GrandTotal

But for each subreport, i want to get the total amount too but this seems to be operating in a running total form.

Below is what i am getting now.

```
OrderDate        Item     qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000

OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        44,000

OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-26       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-26       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-26       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        66,000


GrandTotal     66,000

tonumber({DTtablesales.Amount})
```

The below is how i want the report to be

```
OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-24       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-24       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-24       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000

OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-25       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-25       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-25       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000

OrderDate        Item    qty  Price    Amount
2019-07-26       rice      2   3,000    6,000
2019-07-26       beans     2   5,000    10,000
2019-07-26       fish      2   3,000    6,000

sub_Total        22,000


GrandTotal     66,000
```

Note that the GrandTotal is a TotalRunning Field calculating sum(Amount)

My problem is getting the sub-total

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Reset option on the subtotal under Edit Running Totals menu and reset at the correct group.

[image]

Comment: Thatnk you for saving a life